# Loading text data in python and create a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

say I have a text file with a format similarly to this

```
Q: hello what is your name?
A: Hi my name is John Smith
```

and I want to create a matrix such that it is a 2xn in this case

```
[['hello','what','is',your','name','?', ' '],['hi','my','name','is','John','Smith']]
```

note that the first row has an empty entry because it has 6 strings while second row has 7 strings

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what you're asking to do is pretty simple...but why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
file_data = open('filename.txt').read()
results = filter(None, re.split('A:\s|Q:\s', file_data))
new_results = [re.findall('\w+|\W', i) for i in results]
```

Output:

```
[['hello', ' ', 'what', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'your', ' ', 'name', '?', ' '], ['Hi', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'name', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'John', ' ', 'Smith']]
```

Answer (score 0):

just split the strings, using the split function:

```
with open('txt.txt') as my_file:
    lines = my_file.readlines()
#lines[0] = "Q: hello what is your name?"
#lines[1] = "A: Hi my name is John Smith"
```

then just use

```
output = [lines[0].split,lines[1].split]
```